Replying to same thread using Gmail API
I am trying to implement a feature to reply to an email thread using the Gmail API. Despite my efforts, the replies are being sent as new messages instead of being threaded under the original email. However, they do appear in the correct thread in the overall conversation view.
Here is what I have done so far:
Setting the Thread ID:
gmailMessage.ThreadId = threadId;

Adding the Message ID of the Email Being Replied to:
mimeMessage.Headers.Add("In-Reply-To", msgId);
mimeMessage.Headers.Add("References", msgId);
Ensuring the Subject is the Same:
mimeMessage.Subject = mailMsg.Subject

Despite these steps, the Gmail UI still shows the reply as a new message, though it is recorded in the same thread internally.
Code Snippet for Reference:
private string AddThreadIdToMime(string base64RawMime, string threadId, string msgId)
{
    var mimeMessage = MimeKit.MimeMessage.Load(new MemoryStream(Convert.FromBase64String(base64RawMime.Replace('-', '+').Replace('_', '/'))));
    mimeMessage.Subject = originalSubject;

    mimeMessage.Headers.Add("In-Reply-To", msgId);
    mimeMessage.Headers.Add("References", msgId);

    using (var memory = new MemoryStream())
    {
        mimeMessage.WriteTo(memory);
        return Convert.ToBase64String(memory.ToArray())
            .Replace('+', '-')
            .Replace('/', '_')
            .Replace("=", "");
    }
}

Sending the message:
  gmailMsg.Raw = rawMime;
        gmailMsg.ThreadId = threadId;
    
        UsersResource.MessagesResource.SendRequest msgSendReq = _gmailService.Users.Messages.Send(gmailMsg, userEmail);
        gmailMsg = await msgSendReq.ExecuteAsync();
    }

Question:
What am I missing? Is there any additional step required to ensure that the reply is correctly threaded in the Gmail UI?
Thank you for your help!

In order to ensure that your thread requests work properly, it is essential that you reference several key parameters accurately.
First, I would make sure that I obtain and use the correct “threadId” when calling the “users.send” method. This will link your email to the appropriate thread.
In order to obtain the “threadId”, you can use the APIs Explorer directly available in this Google Developers support article. Fill in the “userId” field (you can use your user email address), then find the “threadId” in the response body. Here’s an example response:
{
  "threads": [
    {
      "id": "1907666c282nsodw",
      "snippet": "Thread-1 On Wed, Jul 1, 2024 at 3:19 PM Peter Parker &lt;admin@example.com&gt; wrote: Message1",
      "historyId": "1234"
    },
...
}

Additionally, you should set the headers in the request correctly. In order to get the necessary information (e.g. “References” header and “In-Reply-To” header, make sure that you use those in the raw email. You can get this by going to the email in the Gmail app, then click on the three-point button on the right side of the message. Next, select “<> Show original”.
Here is an example of the raw email headers:
From: Peter Parker <admin@example.com>
Subject: Re: Hello!
From: Peter Parker <admin@example.com>
To: maryjane@example.com
References: <messageID@mail.gmail.com>
In-Reply-To: <messageID@mail.gmail.com>

After this, upon encoding the above using Base64 URL you can use it in the “raw” parameter. The raw encoded for the example above would be this:
RnJvbTogUGV0ZXIgUGFya2VyIDxhZG1pbkBleGFtcGxlLmNvbT4KU3ViamVjdDogUmU6IEhlbGxvIQpGcm9tOiBQZXRlciBQYXJrZXIgPGFkbWluQGV4YW1wbGUuY29tPgpUbzogbWFyeWphbmVAZXhhbXBsZS5jb20KUmVmZXJlbmNlczogPG1lc3NhZ2VJREBtYWlsLmdtYWlsLmNvbT4KSW4tUmVwbHktVG86IDxtZXNzYWdlSURAbWFpbC5nbWFpbC5jb20-

The full request would look like this:
userId: idOfTheUser@domain.com
{
  "raw": "RnJvbTogUGV0ZXIgUGFya2VyIDxhZG1pbkBleGFtcGxlLmNvbT4KU3ViamVjdDogUmU6IEhlbGxvIQpGcm9tOiBQZXRlciBQYXJrZXIgPGFkbWluQGV4YW1wbGUuY29tPgpUbzogbWFyeWphbmVAZXhhbXBsZS5jb20KUmVmZXJlbmNlczogPG1lc3NhZ2VJREBtYWlsLmdtYWlsLmNvbT4KSW4tUmVwbHktVG86IDxtZXNzYWdlSURAbWFpbC5nbWFpbC5jb20-",
  "threadId": "1907666c282nsodw"
}

In conclusion, in order to reply in a thread you need to make sure you have the correct thread ID, and message ID for which you are responding. References and In-Reply-To need to be the message ID inside the raw message, and then encode the message with Base64 URL.
I also tested different subjects compared to the original message and this was not an issue.
You can try this first in the API explorer here.
